# PG won't concatenate large SQL string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am using Node-Postgres for building an online sign-in application. I can run the following Postgres code no problem using PSQL:

```
DO $$ 
BEGIN 
  IF (SELECT child.child_signedin FROM child WHERE child.child_name = 'mell') IS TRUE THEN 
    INSERT INTO signin (signin_child_id,signin_child_name,signin_intime)
    VALUES (12,mell,'2018-09-24 21:46:06.249+00'); 
  END IF; 
END $$
```

Unfortunately, when I try to make this dynamic using Node_Postgres, I get the following error:

> "error: bind message supplies 3 parameters, but the prepared statement "" requires 0"

Here is my nodejs code:

```
signinTime = new Date();

let text = "DO $$ BEGIN IF (SELECT child.child_signedin FROM child WHERE child.child_name =  $1) IS TRUE THEN INSERT INTO signin (signin_child_id,signin_child_name,signin_intime)\
VALUES ($1,$2,$3); END IF; END $$"

let values = [req.body.childName, req.body.childId, signinTime];
pool.query(text, values, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(err.stack));
            console.log(err.stack.split('\n', 1)[0])
        }
        else {
            res.send('complete')

        };//end else

    })
```

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a spreadsheet next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DO` is for procedural statements that can be executed in various languages, and is not treated by node-postgres as valid SQL. You can either split your statements using some async flow control to achieve the same result.

Example:

```
const selectRes = await pool.query('SELECT child.child_signedin FROM child WHERE child.child_name =  $1', [req.body.childName]);

if (selectRes.rows.length && selectRes.rows[0].child_signedin === true) {
  await pool.query(`INSERT INTO signin
    (signin_child_id,signin_child_name,signin_intime)
      VALUES ($1,$2,$3);`, values);
}
```

Or create a Postgres function and execute it in a query.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I was not aware of that limit in SQL clients. I am going to explore getting this to work using a Postgres function, but otherwise will fall back to the async flow control method you mentioned. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: I removed the "(or any client)" part as that simply isn't true. You can easily run a `DO` statement through JDBC or C (and libpq)